# Why do we need a Rollback command while making a transaction or tell me a when is it appropriate to use "ROLLBACK"

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the code below when I am inserting data in a table then what is the purpose of rollback I should not insert it if I want to rollback so what is the appropriate way to use rollback?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION Insert into dimCustomr Values('xyz',345435353) ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Rollback is typically used when you change your mind during the transaction, or run into problems.

Comment: Your question is unclear here. Can you elaborate? Are you simply asking what does `ROLLBACK` mean? If so, perhaps have a read of BOL? [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql)

Comment: SQL Server does not have implicit transactions, nothing have to commit or rollback in the end of every single DML operation. Therefore, in your case, if you want to rollback, you have to run in the end of script ROLLBACK TRAN

Comment: Read https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the rollback method, you can close the transaction, reverting all associated changes made to the database.
Eg:

[image]

Above diagram illustrate the three query at a time.Tansaction of query1 & query2 were successful but query3 got error. And when query3 got error all transaction will revert.

Comment: Very nice example, but you can't assume that OP knows C#. Also, don't paste code as pictures. You should rather copy and paste as text and format it properly.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I agree with the request to post the code as text but I don’t think having C# here is a problem (although I don’t use it). The code is very clear and could be used in C++ or Java (if mentioned classes were available). So it could IMHO be considered a sort of universal pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

A Rollback is executed if a transaction aborts. It makes the whole Transaction undone.
A transaction could be aborted through several errors that might occour when running the transaction or if you does an unplaned power off of your system.

Comment: Some remark, until SET XACT_ABORT ON specified before transaction was started, SQL Server will not automatically rollback transaction if some non-high severe error encountered..

Answer (score 2):

This is not generally done the way you have written it. BEGIN TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK  block generally has multiple statements.

The purpose of rollback is to "roll back" any and all data modifications have been done between BEGIN TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK in case if any unit of work fails to execute due to any errors.

This is generally useful when you are performing any transaction which will only make sense if a subsequent transaction is successful, otherwise the preceding transaction should not take effect as well.

For simple example. 
In case you are first posting an invoice and then also making a negative inventory change. You begin transaction by posting invoice, then try to make the inventory negative, which fails due to any errors, then the invoice will be reverted back as well when its contained within the same BEGIN TRANSACTION and ROLLBACK block.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback is used to maintain the integrity of the database. So it is either full in or none. For e.g suppose you have 10 rows that you are supposed to insert into a table and on the 8th row there is an issue , then under such a case all the transactions will be rolled back.

Running Transactions inside begin and end  gives us the control over  transaction to either rollback in case of any error or Commit. When we issue Rollback statements any resources that are held by the transactions are also released,

Answer (score 1):

A lot have been said, so let me visualize it with an example:

You want to make big transaction:

You have `Departament` table with columns: `Name`, `Employees`, etc.

You don't allow for a department to exist in table without employees.

Now you have to introduce new departament. So you get the name and make `insert`. Now you have unwanted situation, you have name, but the rest columns is null (`Employee` is null as well). That's ok, because you have script that immediately updates records with number of `Employees`, so you have valid record.

Now, what if something goes wrong (e.g. server is unavailable) between `insert` and `update`? You will be left with invalid record.

That's the reason why you should use `begin transaction` before `insert`. Then, you'd `commit transaction`, if `update` succeeds, but if something goes wrong during updating, you would use `rollback transaction`, so invalid record will be no longer in table (because that change would be rolled back).

Thus, you would have valid and consistent data even if something unexpected happens.

I usually use the following code:

```
begin transaction
begin try
    --do some operations
    --if code was run successfully, we commit transaction
    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    --if something bad happens, we don't know the state of data (consistency, etc.)
    rollback transaction
end catch
```

Comment: ["For good error handling in SQL Server, you need both TRY-CATCH and SET XACT_ABORT ON. Of these two, SET XACT_ABORT ON is the most important."](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, as stated above. ROLLBACK is an option to maintain the integrity of the database. As others have dived into the theory, I will give a short pratical example.

Say I want to update 2 rows in a table. I am a bit scared that the result is not what I want, then I could do the following:

```
 BEGIN TRAN
 UPDATE TableA
 SET ColA = 'New', ColB = 5544
 WHERE ID IN ('112233', '112234')

 SELECT ColA, ColB FROM TableA WHERE ID IN ('112233','112234')-Visual Check

 If the visual check confirms your expectation, COMMIT TRAN.

 If not, ROLLBACK TRAN.
```

A select statement beforehand is a good basis anyway, this can be used as a double check.

Comment: You can't query the table, because it would be **locked** by transaction. You should update your answer and correct code, so it works.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn have you tested this? Please do that and get back to me. You'll see I am not the one who is mistaking here...  :)